# Show current time bar in Lotus Calendar

Tags: calendar, lotus-notes

In Google Calendar, there is a [red line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Bains_line) showing where you are in the progress of you day. It's a simple feature, but quite useful.

Is there a similar feature in Lotus Notes (Calendar)?

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately there is no such feature. This could be achieved by customizing the Java- Code, that generates the Calendar overview (at least since version 8), but would mean a lot of effort. 
Sorry.